# Problems maintaining a custom control's (ascx) states between postbacks when loading said ascx control in page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ascx

I am loading a custom ascx control in page_load of the page that hosts it.
This creating all sorts of issues with postbacks. Mainly, control (textboxes, dropdowns,etc) states are getting reset before the event handlers can process them.

Does any one have any good examples of how I could handle this?

My site design can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640760/changing-a-user-created-control-based-on-content-of-input-from-js-tied-textbox).

I've been told in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647307/finding-events-to-be-processed-in-asp-net) that I can let the control manage its own state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked so many times. Take a look at this for example: [Setting the ControlToValidate on a Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001222/setting-the-controltovalidate-on-a-validator/1001270#1001270)

Answer (score 1):

Viewstate is restored before the page load event, and therefore dynamic controls need to be loaded and added to the page before the page load event or their state won't be restored as you expect.  Do it in the Init event instead.

Comment: This is not true. You can dynamically load controls in Page_Load event just fine. The control will play catch-up. See this http://www.clariusconsulting.net/blogs/vga/archive/2003/08/11/66.aspx